# How do I connect Selenium to localhost?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, mamp

I have some .php files in my MAMP/htdocs folder. I want to perform some automated stuff (I'm pretty much just trying to practice/test scraping on source code I copied from live pages to my machine to avoid getting banned/throttled) in Python Selenium by starting MAMP Servers and running the commands:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("localhost/filename.php")
```

But I get the error:
InvalidArgumentException. My selenium works fine with live webpages.  Is there a special way I need to connect to a localhost that's different than pages over the Internet?

Comment: sounds like the driver failed to launch...  try double-clicking on the driver executable and see what happens (while MAMP is running).  It may be conflicting there since it will also try to setup a server on localhost.

Comment: A command prompt showed up. What does it mean?

Comment: hmm... maybe that's not a good test...  I was hoping it would show an exception or error.    If you don't see a browser launch when the above code runs (with MAMP running) it's likely an issue with mapping DNS entries... on Windows you'd check the "hosts" file.  (I think it's the same on Mac?) Be sure nothing is there that maps localhost to your MAMP host.

Comment: I'm on windows. Are you referring to hosts.py? How can I check this?

Comment: ok, so "WAMP"... on windows it's windowsdir\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts  (no extension... you can open/edit in notepad launched with admin privileges...)

Comment: How do I tell if there is a mapping? I'm seeing the following line: 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal

Comment: if there's not a "#" in front of it, then that's a mapping.  I wouldn't edit the file without checking a tutorial on HOSTS file first... but that seems to be related to docker.  It shouldn't have any affect on Selenium.

Comment: If you don't see the browser launching, something's going wrong when launching the driver.  You might try setting the path to the driver manually and see if that helps... not sure why running WAMP would make any difference there.

Comment: I thought I would need to launch MAMP servers so that the chromedriver browser would be able to open the webpages. Honestly, I'm a bit lost, since there seems to be a lot to take in, and I don't know what I have to research to learn more about this.

Comment: Since it's working when WAMP (windows/apache/mysql/php) is not running, you might just wait to start WAMP server until after the driver launches.  So, driver=webdriver.Chrome(), then wait for user input... launch WAMP, and then tell it to continue.

Comment: I don't think I explained well what the problem is. Whether or not MAMP is running, I can connect to a webpage (like https://google.com) just fine. I'm trying to use MAMP to serve a page on local port 8888, then get that page using selenium webdriver. Opening a live page on with chromedriver, then manually navigating to the desired localhost page also works. It seems my problem is with my usage of the get method.

Comment: You may want to create a new question explaining the issue better.   What you're saying is contradictory... "I can connect to a webpage (like google.com) just fine" + "I don't have Internet access"  = ??

Comment: I think I'm finally getting somewhere and will edit the OP.

Comment: I would start a new question since it's changed so much... but InvalidArgumentException suggests the .get() method's URL validation is failing.  Try with http://...